# Why use the "for" keyword to bind a label in HTML?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the For attribute for in an HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681601/what-is-the-for-attribute-for-in-an-html-tag)

I have been trying to find this out. What is the reason for using the "for=" when you use a label in HTML?

```
<form>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
  <br />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" />
</form>
```

If it's needed then is there some equivalent in HTML 5 or is it the same?

Comment: Seems this question is marked as duplicate and I can't answer here.
You can see [my recent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47489461/7120290)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It makes a click on the label focus the input element it is `for`.

In the example you posted, you simply click on the word `Male` *or* the radio button in order for it to get selected. Without this, you have a much smaller target to click...

> If it's needed then is there some equivalent in HTML 5 or is it the same?

It is not required, but is good practice for labels that have a direct form element to focus on (it wouldn't make much sense for a label that doesn't have a counterpart on a form).

The syntax is the same for HTML 5.

Answer (score 11):

For binds the `<label>` and the `<input>` field together. `for` should point to the `id` of the `<input>`. It is not actually needed, but it is useful for example on radio buttons, where the user can click the label to check the radio button, thus creating a larger click area and a better user experience.

You use `for` the same in way HTML5 as you do in HTML4 or XHTML or whatever you used before.

Answer (score 8):

If you use the `for` attribute of the label, and set its value to the `id` of a related `input` element, most browsers will focus the input element when the label is clicked on. This is especially useful for small elements like checkboxes and radio buttons.