# Corresponding checkboxes through JQuery only work on a parsed trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have searched high and low for a solution and could not find one. It may be because I'm searching in a wrong way but anyway, I can't solve the issue I'm having without any help from the outside.

First a bit of background:

I have an embedded form of the MA platform we are using. Since the adjustments one can make visually on these forms are very limited, I decided to hide the checkboxes on it and create my own. When checking those checkboxes the corresponding ones on the embedded form have to be checked as well.

I also have a checkbox which checks all checkboxes in a list.

Now the issue is, when I check any checkbox that isn't the check-all-checkbox the corresponding boxes on the embedded form do not respond. Whenever I check the check-all checkbox, they do.

I'm getting an unknown error in the snippet generator, which I have never noticed before.

I provided the relevant code in a snippet and added comments where I think stuff is going wrong.

```js
var clickedBox = "default";

  $(".checkall").click(function() {
   clickedBox = this.id;

      // This next block seems to be an issue
      // This is the block that selects all checkboxes when the #checkall one is checked.
      // Normally I have multiple of these lists on the page
   $("#" + clickedBox).change(function () {
    $("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    $("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox").val(parseInt($("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox").val()) + parseInt(1)).trigger("change");
   });

      // This one does something weird as well, on unchecking it multiplies but I can find a solution for this by myself
   $("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox").change(function () {
    if ( $("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length != 0 ) {
     $("#" + clickedBox).prop("checked", false);
     console.log("unchecked a checkbox");
    }
    else if ( $("." + clickedBox + " input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length == 0 ) {
     $("#" + clickedBox).prop("checked", true);
     console.log("checked a checkbox");
    }
   });

   $(".one").change(function () {
    $("#correspondingOne").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
   });
   $(".two").change(function () {
    $("#correspondingTwo").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
   });
   $(".three").change(function () {
    $("#correspondingThree").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
   });
   $(".four").change(function () {
    $("#correspondingFour").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
   });
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">

  <div class="card-header">
    <label>
      <input class="checkall" type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
      <strong><h3>Dropdown list of checkboxes</h3></strong>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkall checkboxes">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="one" /> one </label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="two"/> two </label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="three" /> three </label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="four" /> four </label></p>
  </div>
</div>

Let's regard this one as the MA Form
<br><br>

<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="correspondingOne" /> correspondingOne </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="correspondingTwo" /> correspondingTwo </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="correspondingThree" /> correspondingThree </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="correspondingFour" /> correspondingFour </label>
</form>
```

Anyone that can give me a hand or at least give me a push in the right direction? Would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the code that I posted is the fact that the change functions (below is an example)

```
$(".one").change(function () {
   $("#correspondingOne").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

are included in the $(".checkall").click function. Which means they only get activated after the item with class="checkall" has been clicked.

Moving them outside solves this issue.

I don't recommend using this solution as simply creating new labels for the checkboxes is a much simpler solution as you don't have to parse change triggers and connect one checkbox to another, but it might be interesting to check out the trigger behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

## Check All Checkbox

### HTML

#### `<label>`/`<input>` Pairs

`<label>` attribute [**`[for]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813639/2813224) set to the value of a [**form control**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form-associated_content)'s `#ID` establishes an association between them. When the `<label>` is clicked, the associated `<input>` is triggered by that click event as well.

> ```
> <label for="ID"></label>// Click label...
> <input id="ID" type="checkbox">// ...checkbox will become un/checked
> ```

---

### CSS

#### Pseudo-elements

Each checkbox is hidden and placed at the top of the page. Each `<label>` that's paired to a checkbox has a [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element in place of the associated checkbox.

#### General/Adjacent Sibling Combinators and `:checked` Pseudo-class

There are 2 states to each checkbox: `checked = true/false`. The checkboxes can influence the styles of all preceding sibling elements and their descendants with and without the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). To narrow this down, [**general**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and [**adjacent sibling combinators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`~` and `+` respectively) allow a selector to take a specific path. The example below declares 2 states for a `<label>`:

> **Default** (**adjacent sibling combinator: `+`**)
>
> ```
> input + fieldset label {color:black}
> ```
>
> **Active** (**adjacent sibling combinator: `+`**)
>
> ```
> input:checked + fieldset label {color:red}
> ```
>
> When an `<input>` is `:checked` **and if the next element** is a `<fieldset>` that has nested `<label>(s)`, then change the `<label>'s` text `color:` to `red`.

Replace the adjacent combinator (`+`) with a general combinator (`~`), and the declaration would be:

> **Active** (**general sibling combinator: `~`**)
>
> ```
> input:checked ~ fieldset label {color:red}
> ```
>
> When an `<input>` is `:checked` **and if any sibling thereafter** is a `<fieldset>` that has nested `<label>(s)`, then change the `<label>'s` text `color:` to `red`.

---

### JavaScript

No jQuery was used only plain JavaScript of which was not complex to warrant anything worth mentioning. There is a step-by-step description commented within the Demo if you want to review the function. Although it didn't play a big part in the Demo. [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) was used.

---

### Demo

```js
// See HTMLFormControlsCollection in post

// Reference the form tag
var card = document.forms.card;

// Reference all form controls of form tag
var ui = card.elements;

// Register the ALL checkbox (input#c0) to the change event
ui.c0.addEventListener('change', chxAll);

// Callback function passes Event Object
function chxAll(e) {

  // Declare increment counter outside of loop
  var c = 1;
  // Ternary checks to see if input#c0 is checked
  var all = e.target.checked ? true : false;

  // Loop thruogh the next 4 inputs...
  for (c; c < 5; c++) {

    // Check/uncheck each checkbox in ui HTMLCollection 
    ui[c].checked = all;
  }
  // Open the details tag (optional)
  document.querySelector('.options').open = true;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.2 Consolas;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chx {
  display: none
}

.lab {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lab::before {
  content: '\1f518';
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 2.5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#c1:checked~.header .options .c1::before,
#c2:checked~.header .options .c2::before,
#c3:checked~.header .options .c3::before,
#c4:checked~.header .options .c4::before {
  content: '\1f535';
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 2.5px rgba(15, 102, 241, 0.5);
}

#c0:checked~.header .c0::before,
#c0:checked+#c1:checked~.header .options .c1::before,
#c0:checked~#c2:checked~.header .options .c2::before,
#c0:checked~#c3:checked~.header .options .c3::before,
#c0:checked~#c4:checked~.header .options .c4::before {
  content: '\1f534';
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 2.5px rgba(241, 102, 15, 0.5);
}

#c1:checked+#c2:checked+#c3:checked+#c4:checked+.header .c0::after {
  content: ' Selected';
  color: rgba(15, 102, 241, 1);
  text-shadow: 1.5px 2px 1.75px rgba(15, 102, 241, 0.7);
}

#c0:checked+#c1:checked+#c2:checked+#c3:checked+#c4:checked+.header.header .c0::after {
  content: ' Selected';
  color: rgba(241, 102, 15, 1);
  text-shadow: 1.5px 2px 1.75px rgba(241, 102, 15, 0.7);
}

#c1:not(:checked)~.header .c0::after,
#c2:not(:checked)~.header .c0::after,
#c3:not(:checked)~.header .c0::after,
#c4:not(:checked)~.header .c0::after {
  content: '';
}

#c1:not(:checked)~.header .c0::before,
#c2:not(:checked)~.header .c0::before,
#c3:not(:checked)~.header .c0::before,
#c4:not(:checked)~.header .c0::before {
  content: '\1f518';
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 2.5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
}

.header {
  border: 3px inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.51);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-padding-before: 0.0em;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0.15em;
  -webkit-padding-end: 0.15em;
  -webkit-padding-after: 0.15em;
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 2.5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
  width: 380px;
}

legend {
  height: 35px
}

legend h3 {
  font-size: 1.55rem;
  line-height: 2;
  transform: translateY(-35px);
}

.options {
  background: rgba(3, 9, 27, 0.1);
  border: 3px inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px -1px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
}

summary {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id='card'>

  <input type="checkbox" class="chx" id="c0" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chx" id='c1' />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chx" id='c2' />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chx" id='c3' />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chx" id='c4' />

  <fieldset class='header' name="header">
    <legend>
      <h3>List of Checkboxes</h3>
    </legend>
    <label for='c0' class='c0 lab'> All Options</label>

    <details class="options">
      <summary>Select Options</summary>
      <label for='c1' class='c1 lab'> One </label>
      <label for='c2' class='c2 lab'> Two </label>
      <label for='c3' class='c3 lab'> Three </label>
      <label for='c4' class='c4 lab'> Four </label>
    </details>

  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yours looks like a cleaner method with less hassle to use. Can you, however, point out where I went wrong in my approach? Where is the "empty" error message in the snippet coming from?

Comment: Your use of this expression is wrong: `input:checkbox:not(:checked)` I think. `:not()` CSS pseudo-class is too limited.  *But* jQuery `.not()` method works just as well as its opposite: `.is()` method. I cannot be 100% sure if that'll even work because the 2 blocks of code in the middle are too confusing so I cannot ascertain the purpose. Even if told the purpose, I doubt I could grok its flow and function very well. It looks like you put in time and effort into it but are shaky on some fundamentals. That's why I wrote something from scratch so you could look at things from a diff perspective